# Swift Generic: can't compile the call for a generic function

Tags: swift, generics

I'm not very strong with Swift generics. Please can you help me to solve this compilation error:

```
protocol FooProtol<T> {
  associatedtype T
  func print(_: T)
}

class Foo: FooProtocol {
  typealias T = Bar
  func print(_ bar: Bar) {
    print("\(bar)")
  }
}

class Baz {
  func qux(foo: any FooProtocol) {
    let bar = Bar()
    foo.print(bar) // Compilation error: "Cannot convert value of type 'Bar' to expected argument type '(some FooProtocol).T'"
  }
}
```

Comment: `let bar = Bar` did you mean `let bar = Bar()`?

Comment: Please clean up your code from any typos so we can better understand what the issue is

Comment: Why did you think this would work in the first place? `any FooProtocol` can have any type as `T`, which means you don't know what type `foo.print()` can take. How are you sure that `T` is `Bar`? How about making `foo` of type `any FooProtocol<Bar>` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you really don't need an opaque type here, try making your qux method generic instead:

```swift
func qux<Foo: FooProtocol>(foo: Foo) {
    let bar = Bar()
    foo.print(bar) // Cannot convert value of type 'Bar' to expected argument type 'Foo.T'
}
```

now add a generic constraint:

```swift
func qux<Foo: FooProtocol>(foo: Foo) where Foo.T == Bar {
    let bar = Bar()
    foo.print(bar) // problem solved
}
```